# Why is next giving me Failed to collect page data for /test?

Tags: next.js, turborepo

When I run `turbo run build --cache-dir=".turbo"` for the next project I get the following error.
`Error: Failed to collect page data for /test`

This is my component

```
import { Provider, useHook } from '@test';

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Smethods</h1>
      <Provider>
        <MyPage />
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;

function MyPage() {
  const { method1, method2 } = useHook();

  return (
    <>
      <button>test1</button>
      <button}>test2</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried checking at the routes but couldn find anything wrong :(